# DiscordJS TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Tags: discord, undefined, typeerror

I'm trying to set up a command that when mentioning a member gives them a specific role. However every time I get the same roles undefined error. Can anyone help me out?

My code:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
if (message.content == '!brig'){
    
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'BRIG')
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        target.roles.add('757816527478325391')
    }
})
```

Comment: It means that variable target is undefined. And it is reason of your error message

Answer (score 0):

I made a small modification to your code changing `message.content === '!brig'` to `message.content.includes("!brig")` and it seems like it works fine for me. You can try my code and let me know if anything changes:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content.includes("!brig")) {
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
            (role) => role.name === "BRIG"
        );
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        target.roles.add(role.id);
    }
});

client.login("YOURTOKEN");
```

**Edit:** This code is working with discord.js@13.5.0 but I can't see why it wouldn't work with the latest version (13.6.0 at this moment).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is for some reason all I needed. No clue why this made all the difference but I appreciate it so much!

Comment: I believe the issue was because when you were checking for `messsage.content === '!brigs'` you were only checking for messages with that exact content. But, for your application you want to also include @mentions to a user so you'd need to check for messages which include the content you're looking for instead. Glad I could help!